# Laravel Eloquent query returning non object

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am trying to reduce the number of SQL queries executed. I have a post where I want to get the author of that post and list it on the page.  To reduce the number of SQL queries, I have the following code:

```php
$posts = Post:all();
$posts->load('user');
$posts->first()->user;
```

I get the error/notice "Trying to get property 'user' of a non-object". How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: You'd get this if `$posts->first()` returned `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eager loading reduces this operation to just 2 queries

```
    public function example()
    {
        $posts = Posts::with('user')->get();

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            echo $post->user->name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error can be there because of the Post (or the first post) you are trying to access is not related to any of the users. You can try this to avoid the error.

```
$posts = Post:all();
$posts->load('user');
// Try any one of below.
1) $posts->first()->user ?? '';
2) $posts->first()->user or ''; // in Laravel 5.5 or below
```